# How tell if my android app needs a log in process or not?

Tags: android, theory

I'm building an app where the user will generate lists. I want the user to be able to see the lists after onDestroy() has been called. Does this mean my app will need a log in process so that they can save these lists to their profile, or is there an alternate way of doing this? What about for other users? How will they see their lists and not someone else's list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the generated lists on your server or let the users share their lists, you need an login system. But if you just want the users to save the lists locally on their devices you don't need such a system.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have control over which user is able to see each content, then yes, you're going to need a login system.
Once logged in on the app, an user would be able to see wathever you wish him/her to.